# Error with RequestsForAccessSIQ

Tags: standard-objects, migration, schema

Hi I am working in a migration of metadata from one org to another. I am having the following error related to an object called "RequestsForAccessSIQ".

> Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex. __c )

This kind of error is usally related with some feature not turned on in the target org, like enabling Forecast or Persons Account, etc. Thing is that I have no clue of which configuration is this object related to.

At first I thought it was a custom object but google show me that other people are including this object in their package.xml (also I cannot access it through Setup->Object manager). I didn't found any documentation, I cannot find it through workbench in the schema view, can't query it neither. Any idea what is this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be related to this "Einstein Activity Capture Licence", do you have that?
If not you can bypass this class.

Something like i'm mentioning can be found here --> https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003ghSQAQ